# Does Spring make "calling its own controller" multithread?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an spring boot application that pulls message from an cloud message queue and put it back to a cloud db. I realize that my program is single thread(I am not using request mapping, just pull,process,put to db). I want Spring handle concurrency things. So can I make a dispatcher function, which calls controller in the application with @RequestMapping?

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class GatewayController {
  @RequestMapping("/service")
  public void InvokeService(...) {...}
}
```

I need mutithread to call other service for response, which I don't want it to block others. If I recieve 10 messages, I want it to call /test/service... which have 10 threads processing them.

My question is:

1. Will Spring make the controller multithread?
2. How to call its own controller? Send request to the url? (I don't need response from controller, just let controller call a service to put response in a db on could)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestMapping` is MVC thing - intended to issue http requests. And yes, it uses tomcat under the hood.

If you'll inject `RestController` into your class it won't issue any HTTP requests, you'll only call the controller as a regular bean. If you consume messages in one thread, it won't become multithreaded to answer your first question.

You can, of course, create HTTP request but frankly it's just wrong. So don't do it. This answers your second question to some extent :)

Now, there is nothing wrong conceptually if your microservice acts as a consumer and producer and deals with queues, not all microservices have to be accessible via HTTP.

In order to  work in a multi threaded environment:

1. Check whether you can consume messages in a multi-threaded manner. Maybe the client of your "cloud message queue" offers multi-threaded configuration (thread pool or something).
2. If it's not possible, create a thread pool executor by yourself and upon each message submit the processing task to this thread pool. This will make the processing logic multithreaded with a parallelism level confined by the thread pool size and thread pool configurations.

Comment: I edit the question with code. So you mean if I call /test/service, it won't become mutithread? I need mutithread becasue I need to call other service for response, which I don't want it block others. If I recieve 10 messages, I want it to call different /test/service... which have 10 threads processing them.

Comment: No it won't. If you have single thread that reads from queue, then even if you call http with some kind of http call and not directly, its still a blocking call... Why do you want to deal with rest controllers at all? As I suggested - create a thread pool of message consumer and consume messages in parallel....